# Changing the asset url for the Control Panel

Tags: assets, control-panel

I'm attempting to get the Control Panel assets to load from a CDN instead of locally from Craft.

Going through the config options [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings) and [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) I can't seem to find a way to change the asset URL.

Is there any way to change the asset url (in this case for control panel)?

Comment: Are you trying to get proper Assets (https://craftcms.com/docs/assets) to be served from a CDN (and therefore would be served from both the control panel and front-end of the site) or are you actually trying to get the CSS/JS/Images that Craft uses to style the control panel to be served form a CDN?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification question - I'm attempting to get the assets (JS, CSS, etc) for the Control Panel to be served from CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this.

Problem #1: the URLs generated for control panel resources are based on the Craft install's Site URL (whether that's defined in Settings->General or via the [config setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#siteUrl) and that is taken into account when creating *all* links in Craft, not just for control panel resources requests.

Problem #2: in Craft 2, all control panel resources are actually served through PHP, not the web server.  I suspect even if you found a way around #1, this would cause separate issues.

Comment: Thank you. I came to the same conclusion and hoped someone with more experience on the platform might know a workaround. Thanks again for your help!